# Prevent multiple API requests inside nested components - REACT

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is the best practice to avoid multiple API calls from the nested component (nested as a route) in React?

**Use case**: we dispatch an action that triggers API requests from the nested component's useEffect().

```
<Grandparent>
  <Parent>
      <ChildRoutes/>
  </Parent>
</Grandparent>


function Child = () => {
   useEffect(() => dispatch(someAction()), []);
}
```

***Child component is one of the components inside ChildRoutes.***

Do we need additional condition checks before dispatching or there is a way to prevent remount of parent/grandparent components?

Comment: call api topmost parent.With every rerendering Child component will render and useEffects will called

Comment: Okay, but what if I need to dispatch action only when specific child is mounted? I could pass callback to parent, but these callbacks should also be in useEffect and they will be called multiple times also, like dispatch...

Comment: You could add a dependency to your useEffect hook that will only be changed when you need to make the api call.

Comment: I will try with that, thanks